# Javascript library for fancy font effects

Tags: javascript, css

Sometime before I had come across a javascript library that allowed one to write text in various forms and arrangements. I cant seem to find it, can someone please recommend links ?

Thanks,
Murtaza

Comment: What exactly are your requirements? Can you use SVG/Canvas/TTF fonts? What browsers are you looking to support? Some more details, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few jQuery plugins that deal with text effects. Here are a few:

- [Lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com/)
- [jqIsoText](http://code.google.com/p/jqisotext/)
- [Codename Rainbows](http://labs.dragoninteractive.com/rainbows.php)

Answer (score 0):

Personal feelings aside (I find such effects to be somewhat trite on professional websites, on the other hand if a site is design-driven it may very well be worthwhile to code something custom), there are some libraries out there like [fittext.js](http://fittextjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of 11 jQuery plugins: http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/jquery-plugins-typography/